# HttpWebRequest.GetResponse method stucks for specific urls

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, dotnet-httpclient

Consider the following URL: "http://www.bestbuy.com". This resource is quickly and correctly loaded in all browsers and from all locations.

However, basic C# code currently stucks (ends by timeout for any timeout) for this URL:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

var req = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://www.bestbuy.com");
req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36";
req.Timeout = 30000; // you can set any timeout

using (var resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse()) // stucks and finally ends by timeout here
{
    Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusCode);
    Console.WriteLine(resp.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/M7NZgG

The same code works fine for most other URLs.

Tried different things, but all of them did not help:

- direct loading of HTTPS version ("https://www.bestbuy.com")
- remove calls for UserAgent, AutomaticDecompression and SecurityProtocol setters

HttpClient class also stucks and ends by timeout for that resource.

In Fiddler the response is quickly returned, but it looks strange - it is completely empty:
[image: Fiddler bestbuy]

Comment: Did you capture the traffic and can tell what is stucking? Was the request sended? Did the server provide an answer?

Comment: @thehennyy, yes, I do. In Fiddler the response is quickly received, but it looks strange - it is completely empty. I have added screenshot from Fiddler to the description.

Comment: Bizarre, I played with a working request in fiddler & it may be related to the U/A string - using the one in your post It fails for me as well, using my Firefox U/A it also fails, however it seems to work with Edge's U/A `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134`

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here but many prominent sites take measures to block page scraping using a variety of techniques. If it's not working, it's very likely because Best Buy doesn't want you to do that.

Comment: @AlexK. interesting, thank you for observation!

Comment: @ToddMenier, I agree, that looks like web scraping prevention technique. I actually try to detect spam sites by title, wordpress, domain age and other metrics. Just surprised that fundamental HttpWebRequest and HttpClient classes stuck in some cases. Probably need to fallback to other techniques (like Selenium WebDriver) in such cases.

Comment: That domain reverse lookups to Akamai who have anti-bot services, I wonder if they sniff the browser version & require the headers be in the specific order/format the actual browser uses.